# Deploying default mvc provider hosted app

Tags: 2013, provider-hosted-app

I am trying to test provider hosted apps. I created the default MVC application with no changes. The issue I am running into is permissions for the app.

When I deploy with `AppPermissionsRequests` in the AppManifest.xml, SharePoint will not let me add the app and I receive:

> "Sorry, this app is not supported on your server"

If I do not add in the requests I can add the app, but I cannot open the homepage and receive the error:

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   denied"